# WCF stops working suddenly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm having a problem using a WCF call from a Web application to my WCF service running on same server. This call works fine for some time, but then stopped working all of a sudden, and has not worked since.

I have web application hosted at https://www.example.com/CallWebService/Default.aspx

above url is making call to WCF service at https://www.example.com/sampleservice/service.asmx.

both are hosted on same server different directory.

It was working correctly, without any change in application code,and without any server side change, suddenly it is giving error message :

> "An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://www.example.com/sampleservice/service.asmx. This could be due
>   to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly
>   with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."

Tried with traceviewer showing following error :

> "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
>   making the HTTP request to
>   https://www.example.com/sampleservice/service.asmx. This could be due
>   to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly
>   with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
>   ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---&gt;
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Can any one suggest anything on this ?,i have been stuck into this since 3 days.... found no working solution

Comment: Looks like you use SSL. Make sure your certificate hasn't expired

Comment: @KevinGosse ssl expiring on 31/03/2019, actually My certificate was expiring on 23-03-2017, so i renew my ssl and re install it on 18-03-2017

Comment: You might be hitting an exception which is not handled in your code. Try logging.

Comment: i tried with traceviewer, exception written above...

Comment: Add logging in your code and you'll come to know the actual stacktrace of the exception in your code

Comment: @KarthikAMR  can you give me reference about how to do it ?

Comment: For simplicity, add a static class named logger and have a property of a file class. Write the exceptions in a file using the Logger class. 
Or you can create a new files and write exception every time when you hit an error in the catch block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139328/discussion-between-user3782114-and-karthik-amr).

Comment: I noticed that it has been stopped working since i install new ssl certificate, but i also try reinstalling old ssl again as there were still few day left before expiry but issue do not resolved.

Comment: I checked Test SSL Protocol Support on https://foundeo.com for may domain  it shows that SSLv2 and SSLv3 is disabled, and in my Default.aspx.cs there is line System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; could it be causing the issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue it was related to network, check your load balancer and see if there is any error, usually network issue if it happens suddenly.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).