# An error occurred while making the HTTPS request to service? No trace on service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

I have a solution containing 2 WCF services Selfhosted in one Window Service, one for regular http and one for https. The client can connect to the http service but when connecting to the https service I get :

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://192.168.130.29:44390/MyAppService/SSl. This could be due to
>   the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with
>   HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of
>   the security binding between the client and the server.

I have tripple checked the URL and its correct.

First I activate WCF trace on client, I can see this

**Receive bytes on connection https://192.168.130.29:44390/MyAppService/Sll**

```
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://192.168.130.29:44390/MyAppService/Sll. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(Exception E)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckWriteSideResponseProcessing()
at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteCallDone(ConnectStream stream, ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.CallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.IOError(Exception exception, Boolean willThrow)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.HandleWriteHeadersException(Exception e, WebExceptionStatus error)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ResumeIOWorker(Object result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.WakeupPendingIO(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://192.168.130.29:44390/MyAppService/Sll. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
```

I turn on WCF trace on the service and I get a log but there is no incoming messages!?

I have checked that the certificate is installed on the server and that it is valid. If it would not be found, then the https service would never start.

The certificate is also installed on the client computer and i can see that it is valid there as well.

If I run this solution(both service and client) localy on my dev computer, then it works great!

Could this be a blocked port on the server? I have never hade to open any ports before for this.

**Edit :** Code for how the channelfactory is created on the client side.

```
private async Task<ChannelFactory<T>> CreateChannelFactory(LoginTypeBase loginType, MyAppToken token)
{
    var service = await _ConsulService.GetServiceBlocking(loginType.MyAppServicesToUse, forceRefresh: true, token: new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Token);

    if (service == null)
        throw new MyAppServiceCommunicationException();

    var uri = loginType.GetMyAppClientServiceURL(service.Address, service.Port);

    var header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(nameof(MyAppToken), nameof(MyAppToken), token);
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri, header);

    ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = null;
    if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard || loginType.LoginType == LoginType.UsernamePasswordSecure)
    {
        var binding = new NetHttpsBinding("netHttpsBinding");
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

        serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), binding, endpointAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        var binding = new NetHttpBinding("netHttpBinding");
        serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), binding, endpointAddress);
    }

    serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());
    serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomMessageInspectorBehavior());


    var v = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceEndpoint);
    return v;
}
```

Edit 2 : 
I can see in the event log > Security Audit Failure right when doing the call. It says :

> An account failed to log on Failure Information:  Failure
>   Reason:       Unknown user name or bad password.  Status:         0xC000006D  Sub
>   Status:       0xC0000064 Process Information:     Caller Process ID:  0x22c
>     Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe
>
> Network Information:  Workstation Name:   TITAN   Source Network
>   Address:  -   Source Port:        -
>
> Detailed Authentication Information:  Logon Process:      Schannel
>     Authentication Package: Kerberos    Transited Services: -   Package Name
>   (NTLM only):  -   Key Length:     0

And

> Detailed Authentication Information:  Logon Process:      Schannel
>     Authentication Package: Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
>     Transited Services: -   Package Name (NTLM only):   -   Key Length:     0
>
> This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on
>   the computer where access was attempted.
>
> The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which
>   requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the
>   Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or
>   Services.exe.
>
> The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested.
>   The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).
>
> The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on
>   the system requested the logon.
>
> The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request
>   originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left
>   blank in some cases.

Comment: Try enable TLS in your client code.

Comment: And make use of the proper DNS name of the service, I doubt the SSL certificate will be registered on the IP address.

Comment: @LeszekRepie It is already set to ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 by default? Should this be changed in any way?

Comment: @jessehouwing I tryed to change the UEL to https://titan:44390/MyServiceService/Sll but get the same exception. I have used IP address before between these computers with certificate so IP should work fine.

Comment: Do I maybe have to bind the certificate on the client as well? Not only setting it as https with no client certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)