# WCF Client - connect to service

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, client

I have problem connection to wcf service over https. I didn't created wcf service. In Internet Explorer when I set url end open page, ask me to write username and password.

I opend new C# project, wanted to add new service reference but each time I get error:

> There was an error downloading 'https://address/path/service.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://address/path/service.svc.svc'.
>   An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://address/path/service.svc.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I also tried to download wsdl file and with add service reference added this local wsdl file. It passed but now when I start client I got exception:

> The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

```
try
{
    ServiceReference1.IService stub = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
    stub.calculate("test");
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
}
```

but I don't have options of ClientCredentials in stub object???

app.config

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/></startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://address/path/service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceClient` by [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.masterdataservices.serviceclient.aspx) has a property called `ClientCredentials`, although `IService` does not. Maybe try to change your variable type from `IService` to `ServiceClient`?

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient stub = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;  
stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;  

// Treat the test certificate as trusted  
stub.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
```

Here is a link to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows how to authenticate with username / password

Comment: Thanks, now I have option for credentials but I now I get error when i calling method:  An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://address/path/Service.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Comment: There are couple good pointers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf). It is hard to be more specific without seeing certificate details. Also, you can try [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see if you can get more details on the error, as well as try capturing inner exception

Comment: Thanksi just put:

Answer (score 1):

I put before calling method:

```
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Code:

```
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;            //System.Net.ServicePointManager.
        try
        {
            var stub = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
            stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
            //stub.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
            //System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            stub.calculate("Test");
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
```