# How to add SSL Certificate enabled web service to windows service?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

I've a windows service developed in C#.NET and my client has a web service developed in Java. I need to connect to their web service from my windows service for making transaction. But the client web service is HTTPS and certificate enabled web service. Whenever I'm trying to "Add Service Reference" using Visual Studio 2017 then I'm getting the following error:

> There was an error downloading 'https://xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx?wsdl/$metadata'.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx?wsdl'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at https://xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I have also installed their certificate in my local machine and I can test their API through SoapUI but only while I'm trying to add their ws as a reference to my Windows service using Visual Studio then I'm hitting the above error. I would appreciate any help on the above.

**My problem is not similar as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)** 
Because in the other question the person is having issue to call WCF to WCF by code. But I'm hitting the error while trying to add the Service Reference from the visual studio. Also, I'm trying to call a Java Web service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)