# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The specified network name is no longer available?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, exception, timeout

In WCF service I am using webhttpbinding tag with following configurations

```
<binding writeEncoding="UTF-8" 
         name="AXServiceBinding" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
         sendTimeout="infinite" 
         receiveTimeout="infinite" 
         openTimeout="infinite" 
         closeTimeout="infinite" 
         maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
```

It performs the expected operation but in log I am getting the following exception:

> Error occurred during processing: The specified network name is no longer available. This often indicates that the HTTP client has prematurely closed the underlying TCP connection.
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The specified network name is no longer available. This often indicates that the HTTP client has prematurely closed the underlying TCP connection. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The specified network name is no longer available.

Comment: I highly doubt this is  something we can diagnose, specially as we don't know what the client software is doing. It can be anything in your network, firewalls, proxyservers, virus software, something in your code.

Comment: @rene..any suggestions? What can i try to fix this or what are the possible reasons for this kind of issue because the configuration i am using in my service should not give the time out issue that what i believe.

Comment: I don't know, get the logging of  the client that  prematurely closed the tcp connection? I doubt it is a timeout issue.

Comment: @rene..if its not related to timeout than what else it can be?

Comment: *It can be anything in your network, firewalls, proxyservers, virus software, something in your code.* ... repeated from my first comment. There is nothing we can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, open Administrative Tools to access Windows Features and make sure SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support is enabled. Make sure to restart your Windows system to make sure the changes take effect.