# How to enable server side SSL3.0, TSL1 on Windows server 2016 (IIS 10)?

Tags: windows, wcf, ssl, iis-10

I know Windows Server 2016 by default disabled SSL3.0 and TSL1 for IIS 10 service.

My question is how to enable them?

I followed the steps in the thread
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a6f6fa60-03fb-49f6-b356-de4aa7633738/how-to-disable-tls-and-enable-ssl30-on-iis?forum=winserverNIS

But, it still doesn't work for me.
SSL3.0 and TLS1 is not enabled at the server side.

I am trying to fix the issue on following thread. But, I don't want toto change the client code. I want to figure out a way to allow Windows Server 2016 to allow SSL3.0 and TLS1. 
[WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)

Who can help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Jun

Comment: Use Wireshark and IIS Crypto to troubleshoot further.

Comment: I looked at this topic https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/80088a23-b0eb-4f15-9125-6907a56db3fb/ssl-3-is-not-enabled-in-windows-server-2012-r2?forum=winserver8gen , he has the same issue like me.

Comment: You can read a thousand posts but nothing would be useful if you don't understand the details behind.

Answer (score 2):

I used this tool https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/ and work for me. 
Be sure you have configured your client to use SSL 3. The changes that made the tool were this

```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL]
  "EventLogging"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\AES 128/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\AES 256/256]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\DES 56/56]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\NULL]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 128/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 40/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 56/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\CipherSuites]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA256]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA384]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA512]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\ECDH]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Client]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Client]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
  "Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```