# Marketing cloud SOAP API Retrieve request timeout exception

Tags: c#, soap, webservice-client, exacttarget, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to download the subscribers from marketing cloud using the SOAP API and it throws the following exception after couple of iterations.

[image: ExceptionDetails]

It does not fail consistently. Sometimes it completes 50 iterations and fails and sometimes it fails after 5 or 10 iterations.

Here is the code I am using to make the retrieve request:

```
public List<Subscriber> GetSubscribers(string RequestId = null)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        _lstSubscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;

        RetrieveRequest retrieveRequest = new RetrieveRequest();
        retrieveRequest.ObjectType = "Subscriber";

        string[] props = { "Client.ID", "CreatedDate", "EmailAddress", "EmailTypePreference", "ID", "PartnerKey", "SubscriberKey", "UnsubscribedDate" };
        retrieveRequest.Properties = props;

        retrieveRequest.ClientIDs = new ClientID[] { _clientID };
        //retrieveRequest.QueryAllAccounts = true;
        //retrieveRequest.QueryAllAccountsSpecified = true;

        String requestId = RequestId; 
        String response = string.Empty;
        int tryCount = 0;
        try
        {
            RunRetrieveRequest(client, out requestId, out response, retrieveRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (response == "MoreDataAvailable")
            {
                tryCount++;
                if (tryCount <= 10)
                {

                }

                retrieveRequest.ContinueRequest = requestId;
                RunRetrieveRequest(client, out requestId, out response, retrieveRequest);
            }
        }
        return _lstSubscribers;
    }

    private void RunRetrieveRequest(SoapClient client, out string RequestID, out string Response, RetrieveRequest Request)
    {
        List<Subscriber> lstSubscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
        APIObject[] results = null;
        do
        {
            Response = client.Retrieve(Request, out RequestID, out results);

            Subscriber subscriber = null;
            if (Response != null && results != null)
            {
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    subscriber = (Subscriber)result;
                    _lstSubscribers.Add(subscriber);
                }
            }
            Request = new RetrieveRequest();
            Request.ContinueRequest = RequestID;
        } while (Response == "MoreDataAvailable");
    }
```

Here is the config. I have tried changing the timeout attributes from 30 to 59, but this didn't help.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SoapBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="SoapBinding1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="SoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" />
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://mySubDomain.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding"
            contract="sfmc.Soap" name="Soap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I will appreciate any help or suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this issue and posting the answer as it may help someone else struggling with a similar issue. The Salesforce marketing cloud API (both SOAP and REST) has stopped supporting the default TLS 1.0 protocol. So I needed to add the following code before I sent any request to the API.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

The following link has more explained insights on the same.

[WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)