# Getting server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS when doing load test

Tags: c#, soap, soapui

I've a middle tier written in C# which consume a Soap endpoint provided by a client.
TLS 1.2 is mandatory , So I've this line in my code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Also I've a P12 file which i read by this way

```
DeviceClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverpath"].ToString(),ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwd"].ToString());
```

I'm able to get a response using sequential call. But when simulating a load test using soap ui, for some requests, I get the following error message:

> Server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS.This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Any ideas?
Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)

Comment: Hi John, I've been on the link, the question is different as for my case some requests work and for others i get the error. And it only happens with a load test. Thanks by the way